# How zip download from DigitalOcean spaces in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, zip, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I have some folders in spaces. I want to create a zip of a folder that has some sub-folders. But I can not do that. I am able to do it in local storage. But from spaces I can not do. My project is in php/laravel. Can anyone help me out in this please?

```
$zipFile->addDirRecursive(Storage::path('public/'.$path))
        ->saveAsFile($outputFilename);
return $zipFile->outputAsSymfonyResponse($outputFilename);
```

This is the code I do zip from my local storage. How to do it from spaces?

Answer (score 0):

// **Step 1:** Install package

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

// **Step 2:** Add this code in config/filesystems.php

```
'spaces' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
    'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
    'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('DO_SPACES_URL'),
],
```

// **Step 3:** Add this code in .env file

```
DO_SPACES_KEY=your_key
DO_SPACES_SECRET=your_secret
DO_SPACES_REGION=your_region
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://your_region.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACES_BUCKET=your_bucket
DO_SPACES_URL=https://your_bucket.your_region.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

// **Step 4:** Add this code in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function download($file)
{
    $path = Storage::disk('spaces')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->getObjectUrl(env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'), $file);
    return redirect($path);
}
```

// **Step 5:** Add this code in your route

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', [YourController::class, 'download'])->name('download');
```

// **Step 6:** Add this code in your view

```
<a href="{{ route('download', $file) }}">Download</a>
```

**I tried to explain in detail, I hope it helps :)**

Comment: thanks for your help but it is not working for me. As I want to zip a folder with sub-folders.

Comment: he asked to zip files and to download not to just download